# Find Last seven day record

Tags: php, mysql

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$countreview= mysql_query("SELECT count(review),
                                  time
                        FROM review
                        WHERE time BETWEEN ($today - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND $today
                        GROUP BY time");
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you need? The title alone is not enough.

Comment: what you want exactly still we can't get your question?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
SELECT * from users where created_time > (NOW()-INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE( '$today'),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND '$today'
```

if you want compare with current time use `now()`

```
time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE( NOW()),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$sql="SELECT  * FROM  review  WHERE DATE(time) = DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 7)";
```

I hope this is what you are searching for

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your MySQL WHERE clause to return records that were created within the last 7 days/week:

`created >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 day)`

Also use NOW() in the subtraction to give hh:mm:ss resolution. So to return records created exactly (to the second) within the last 24hrs, you could do:

`created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 day)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find it simplest :

```
$sevenDayOld = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days 00:00:00'));
$SQL = "SELECT count(review),time, FROM review
                    WHERE time > '" . $sevenDayOld ."'
                    GROUP BY time";
```